# How do joins and query array of ids as a string into another table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm storing the multiple ids as string in another table. Now I need to join id's table and query the joined table

**Model**

**user.rb**

```
#columns
id:
name: string

# associations
has_one :user_store
```

**store.rb**

```
#columns
id:
name: string
```

**user_store.rb**

```
#columns
id: integer
user_id: integer
store_ids: string

#association
belongs_to :user
```

I store the multiple store ids in user_store's store_ids column

example
UserStore.first =>

```
#<UserStore:0x00005636e9ae7358
 id: 1,
 user_id: 1,
 stores: "31, 32, 33, 34, 35",
 created_at: Wed, 25 Aug 2021 19:24:37.292280000 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 25 Aug 2021 19:24:37.292280000 UTC +00:00>
```

How do I **query to Store** table **from **UserStore****?

**Ruby - 3.0.1**

**Rails - 6.1.3.2**

**Postgres - 10**

Comment: "I'm storing the multiple ids as string in another table." - *Don't do that*. Create a join table instead to avoid violating [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). This will let you simply join the table with a sane query. https://medium.com/pragmatic-programmers/antipattern-format-comma-separated-lists-4228d7c9c663

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Postgres function `string_to_array` to convert this `"31,32,33,34,35"` string type to array type and use the `unnest` function to convert array elements to records.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE user_store (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    user_id int4 NOT NULL,
    store_id int4 NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_user_store(p_user_id integer, p_store_id character varying)
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
     
    insert into user_store 
    (
        user_id,
        store_id,
        created_at 
    )
    select 
        p_user_id, 
        t1.store_ids::integer, 
        now()
    from 
        unnest(string_to_array(p_store_id, ',')) t1 (store_ids);
    
    return true; 
    
exception 
when others then 
    return false; 

END;
$function$
;
```

Calling this function for testing:

```
select * from test.insert_user_store(1, '31,32,33,34,35');
```

Result:

| user_id | store_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 31 | 2021-11-01 07:31:22.351 |
| 1 | 32 | 2021-11-01 07:31:22.351 |
| 1 | 33 | 2021-11-01 07:31:22.351 |
| 1 | 34 | 2021-11-01 07:31:22.351 |
| 1 | 35 | 2021-11-01 07:31:22.351 |